# LINQ to Entities with AddMonth method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my code:

```
 return Newsletterctx.Subscribers.Count(o =>
     o.Validated == false &&
     o.ValidationEmailSent == true &&
     o.SubscriptionDateTime.AddMonths(1) < DateTime.Now);
```

I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Perhaps you can shift the date to test against instead:

```
DateTime testDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
return Newsletterctx.Subscribers.Count
            (o => o.Validated == false 
             && o.ValidationEmailSent == true 
             && o.SubscriptionDateTime < testDate);
```

Comment: In this case, it throws exception when declaring testDate variable:
 
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
CS$<>8__locals0 was null.

Comment: @İlkinElimov Yes, if the sequence contains null references, that might happen. You can fix that by first filtering them out with `.Subscribers.Where(o => o != null).Count(o =>...`

Answer (score 46):

You can use SqlFunctions classvar;

```
 today =  DateTime.Now; return Newsletterctx.Subscribers.Count(o =>
 o.Validated == false &&
 o.ValidationEmailSent == true &&
 SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month",1,o.SubscriptionDateTime) <today);
```

Comment: I haven't seen SqlFunctions before, interesting stuff.

Comment: Worked for me too Thanks whitestream!

Answer (score 3):

Now,  EntityFramework, Version=6 above, you can jus use **System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions**

```
return Newsletterctx.Subscribers.Count(o =>
 o.Validated == false &&
 o.ValidationEmailSent == true &&
  DbFunctions.AddMonths(o.SubscriptionDateTime,1) < DateTime.Now);
```

However, in this case, use the temp variable testDate that answered by Fredrik Mörk uses less resources.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Datetime outside the request because you are in the LINQ TO ENTITIES that don't use System.Datetime Library.

If you wish to use a fix date the you can define it outside the request as

DateTime compareDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(x);