# How to add Month in date time and Compare with another date time in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following controller action method

```
public ActionResult BondCompletion(DateTime? ToDate)
    {
        List<BondCompletionViewModel> bondCompletionViewModel = new List <BondCompletionViewModel>();
        if (ToDate != null)
        {
            bondCompletionViewModel = db.Employees.Select(y => new 
            { 
                y.JoiningDate ,
                y.Commitments ,
                y.EmployeeId ,
                y.Name 
            })
            .Where(x => x.JoiningDate.AddMonths(x.Commitments.Value).Month == ToDate.Value.Month)
                .Select(z => new BondCompletionViewModel
                {
                    EmployeeId = z.EmployeeId.Value,
                    EmployeeName = z.Name,
                    StartDate = z.JoiningDate,
                    EndDate = z.JoiningDate//.AddMonths(x.Commitments.Value)
                }).ToList();
        }

        return View(bondCompletionViewModel);
    }
```

In above method Commitments is nullable int and JoiningDate is datetime. when I run this if showing following error

“**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**”

Please guide me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Your problem is that linq to entities has to form a sql query out of the lamda expressions... similar question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529361/linq-to-entities-with-addmonth-method but your query also depends on another database value

Comment: What about simply changing it to 

.Where(x => x.JoiningDate.Month == ToDate.Value.AddMonths(-1*x.Commitments.Value).Month)
                .Select(z => new BondCompletionViewModel
                {
                    EmployeeId = z.EmployeeId.Value,
                    EmployeeName = z.Name,
                    StartDate = z.JoiningDate,
                    EndDate = z.JoiningDate//.AddMonths(x.Commitments.Value)
                }).ToList();

Comment: @GauravSharma That would have the same issue.  It still has to translate the `AddMonths` to SQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is not linq. Your issue is that EF does not know how to convert that statement (z.JoiningDate.AddMonths(x.Commitments.Value)) to SQL.

If you ToList() before the select it should work.

Else you should use

```
EntityFunctions.AddMonths(z.JoiningDate, x.Commitments.Value)
```

which EF can indeed convert to SQL

In other words

```
.Select(z => new BondCompletionViewModel
{
   EmployeeId = z.EmployeeId.Value,
   EmployeeName = z.Name,
   StartDate = z.JoiningDate,
   EndDate =  EntityFunctions.AddMonths(z.JoiningDate, x.Commitments.Value)
}).ToList();
```

**Edit:**
DbFunctions is the new EF 6 class to use instead of EntityFunctions

Comment: EntityFunctions is an absolute function. I got my solution from your ans. But update EntityFunctions to DbFunctions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [EntityFunctions.AddMonths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412484(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database.

*Usage*

```
EntityFunctions.AddMonths(z.JoiningDate, x.Commitments.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SqlFunction Class:

```
.Where(x => SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month",x.Commitments.Value,x.JoiningDate).Month == ToDate.Value.Month)
```