# I wants to date month and year add 2 month later in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In that code Resignlastdate I need two months later

```
 DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Now;
 var Resignuser = db.Employees.Where((m => (
    && !m.IsDeleted && m.IsActive
    && m.IsResign == true
    && new DateTime(m.ResignLastDate.Value.Year,m.ResignLastDate.Value.Month + 2 , 1)  >= dtFrom `that date i need two month later date`
    && m.StatusId != 3
    && m.StatusId != 4)))
   .Select(m => new
   {
       Display = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName,
                 GUID = m.GUID
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: You could try declaring the 2 months later date beforehand, e.g. `DateTime twoMonths = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);` and then using it to compare, e.g. `&& twoMonths >= m.ResignLastDate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities with AddMonth method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529361/linq-to-entities-with-addmonth-method)

Comment: let me try  Keyur

Comment: Pmarlet i wants Resigndate date 2 month later

Comment: Keyur it's not working. thank you

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Now;
var Resignuser = db.Employees.Where((m => (
                && !m.IsDeleted && m.IsActive
                && m.IsResign == true
                && SqlFunctions.DateAdd("month",2,m.ResignLastDate)  >= dtFrom
                && m.StatusId != 3
                && m.StatusId != 4)))
                 .Select(m => new
                 {
                     Display = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName,
                     GUID = m.GUID
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For DbFunction  use System.Data.Entity

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Now.AddMonth(2);
var Resignuser = db.Employees.Where((m => (
                && !m.IsDeleted && m.IsActive
                && m.IsResign == true
                && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.ResignLastDate)  >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dtFrom)
                && m.StatusId != 3
                && m.StatusId != 4)))
                 .Select(m => new
                 {
                     Display = m.FirstName + " " + m.LastName,
                     GUID = m.GUID
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks, but the previous Solution is working Properly